# Sql Php Syntax Error :(

Tags: php, sql

Any ideas why I cant get the following to work?

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE DAY = '$_POST[Day]' AND TIME = '$_POST[Time]')";
```

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Thanks :)

Comment: Three questions within a 24 hour period; you really need to read and understand tutorials on how PHP and MySQL work. You want people to find the errors and fix it for you. This isn't CODES-R-US.

Comment: Is there a daily limit on the questions someone can ask? If the OP's questions could be improved, or if there are resources he/she should be checking before asking, it'd be helpful to make suggestions in that direction.

Comment: You're right @Caleb - @OP: Google "php mysqli pdo tutorials prepared statements sql injection". And there isn't a set limit as per se, however fixing code, teaching, is not our job. If the OP had a real problem, then I for one am more happy to help. This question wasn't closed for nothing, I wasn't the only one part of closing it. First the OP goes from `C+` question to PHP, to SQL. Learning curves aren't taught on SO, but from tutorials, which obviously aren't part of "the equation" in the OP's case. The "resources", are already out there. `$out_there="Google and StackOverflow.";` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove ending ")" bracket and change $_POST[Day] with $_POST['Day'] and $_POST[Time] with $_POST['Time']

Answer (score 3):

replace code 
FROM

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE DAY = '$_POST[Day]' AND TIME = '$_POST[Time]')";
```

TO

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE DAY = '$_POST[Day]' AND TIME = '$_POST[Time]'";
```

I think that ) closing bracket is make error

Answer (score 1):

#### Replace your current query with;

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE DAY = '". $_POST['Day'] ."' AND TIME = '". $_POST['Time'] ."'";
```

Please don't pass raw _POST's into your query

- I've treated both `_POST` values as strings, as that is what it looked like you tried to accomplish.
- Removed an extra `)`
- Altered array keys to become strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need {}

```
$sql2= "SELECT * FROM `Persons` WHERE DAY = '{$_POST[Day]}' AND TIME = '{$_POST[Time]}'";
```

or concatinate your $_POST

```
$sql2= "SELECT * FROM `Persons` WHERE DAY = '".$_POST[Day]."' AND TIME = '".$_POST[Time]."'";
```